# Javascript object shows different value

Tags: javascript

I know it sounds weird, but I am having tough issue here. In the picture, `Items` is `Array(0)`, but inside it is `Array(9)`. I can't access it when I say `data.Items.length` or `data.Items[0]`. Why does it look like that and how can I access it?

[image]

Here's how I create it:

```
var data = {};
data = [];
```

Then push data in a loop into `data`.

Comment: Can u please put in some code that generates it ?

Comment: warning: the console lies

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari, done.

Comment: Hover over or click on the `i`. That's the explanation for the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: the `i` is the middle letter of `lie` :p

Comment: @FelixKling ^^ need your hammer (I know this sounds super weird :p)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: lol.... I have one too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41492035/218196 ;)

Comment: I got it, guys, thanks a lot. Seems like I pass the data before it is filled up.